# Does token order matter in a ODBC connection string for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, odbc, azure-sql-database

I am trying to inject the password part of my connection string at runtime, so I can save the password securely. Previously I exactly replaced the part where the password token was placed, with the actual password.

Now I tried just appending it at the end, and the connection is failing. **Does the order of the tokens in the connection string really matter?**

Previously my connection string would look like this:

> Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:[server
> address],1433;Database=[name];Uid=[username];Pwd=[password];Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection
> Timeout=30;

Now the failing connection string looks like this:

> Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:[server
> address],1433;Database=[name];Uid=[username];Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection
> Timeout=30;Pwd=[password];

I get two errors when trying to add Pwd token at the end:

> ERROR [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid
> connection string attribute
>
> ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Login failed for user '[username]'

The code I use to construct the connection string looks like this:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString(string connectionString, string server, string masterPassword)
    {
        if (connectionString.Contains($"Server=tcp:{server}"))
            connectionString = connectionString + $"Pwd={masterPassword};";

        return connectionString;
    }
```

Comment: I would guess your string replacement (or indeed the original string) doesn't include a semicolon (;) after one of the components of the connection string.

Comment: I compared old/new connection string in Visual studio code, where I tried to highlight the connection string (it will highlight identical strings) and I have all semicolons. The strings are indeed identical except for the placement of the password token

Comment: Place a `Debug.Print(connectionString)` before the return statement and post the result. Could be a missing semicolon.